# Could not resolve type Document in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to add a CSS class dynamically on the click of a button on the **body** tag. So I am using the `DOCUMENT` object of angular. Here is the code

```
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";

... component code

constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

addClass() {
    this.document.body.classList.add("any_class");
}
```

but this is showing errors

```
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Could not resolve type Document.
[0]   {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Could not resolve type","line":50,"character":53,"context":{"typeName":"Document"}}
[0]     at \node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:664:27
[0]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
[0]     at validateMetadata (D:\QPP Workspace\QWC\QWC\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:652:42)
[0]     at MetadataCollector.getMetadata (D:\QPP Workspace\QWC\QWC\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:507:17)
[0]     at LowerMetadataCache.getMetadataAndRequests (ProjectPath\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\lower_expressions.js:264:39)
[0]     at LowerMetadataCache.ensureMetadataAndRequests (ProjectPath\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\lower_expressions.js:209:27)
[0]     at LowerMetadataCache.getRequests (ProjectPath\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\lower_expressions.js:204:21)
[0]     at ProjectPath\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\lower_expressions.js:146:36
[0]     at ProjectPath\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:2601:86
[0]     at reduceLeft (ProjectPath\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:2274:30)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
[0]     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
[0]     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
[0]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
[0]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

What is the issue? I am using **angular5**. And is there any other way to add class dynamically?

Comment: I would suggest you to checkout this 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20351

A quick 'any' type instead of 'Document' might fix this

Comment: I just found out that import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser"; is deprecated, use import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll get this error if using something like

```
@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document
```

with your compiler settings in your tsconfig.json set to

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "strictMetadataEmit": true
}
```

It turns out that the angular compiler doesn't understand the type `Document` when working out the metadata for injectable parameters, even though it understands the injection token `DOCUMENT`, and Typescript understands type `Document`.

This is documented here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20351

The workaround that I use is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class MyService {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document?: any) {
    this._document = document as Document;
  }

  private _document?: Document;

...
```

This uses `any` for the injection signature (making angular happy), but gives you Typescript types within the class.

---

Note: This is no longer an issue with Ivy on Angular 9 or later. You can just use:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) readonly document: Document
) {}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with object window. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can add "/** @dynamic */" before your component's decorator:

```
/** @dynamic */
@Component({
```

to suppress the error as mentioned here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20351#issuecomment-344009887 and here https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#strictmetadataemit

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: As the comments state, it is a bad practice. To use at your own risk. ;)**

You can directly use `document` in typescript without any import.

Just do: `document.body.classList.add("any_class");`.

Comment: It's a bad practice to directly manipulate the dom in angular

Comment: it wont work if you run it outside a browser. Search for Angular Universal to know more about Server Side Rendering that does not uses a full browser to render the page in the server.